# Handle deep links with multiple environments for the same app on iOs using react-native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, deep-linking

I have a react-native app with multiple environments.

Dev, prod, ... Which means that I have multiple 'copies' of the app installed on the phone App Dev, App Prod.

These are under a different bundle identifier:

- com.myapp.dev
- com.myapp.prod

I use deep links to open the app, **this works perfect on Android because it asks with which app you want to open it**, but on iOS it just opens the first app that founds installed  and i can't find the way to, for example:

- Launch `develop-app://whatever/1` and open it in the Dev app
- Launch `prod-app://whatever/1` and open it in the Prod app

What am i missing?

This are my defined url types:

[image]

Also the `apple-app-site-association` file looks like this:

```
{
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [
            {
                "appID": "1234.com.myapp.dev",
                "paths": ["*"]
            },
            {
                "appID": "1234.com.myapp.prod",
                "paths": ["*"]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**Update**

- The first problem that i found was that the `apple-app-site-association` wasn't using a `Content-Type` header, so, the app could not recognize the file.
- The paths that each environment should recognize should be defined:

```
{
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [
            {
                "appID": "1234.com.myapp.dev",
                "paths": ["/dev/*"]
            },
            {
                "appID": "1234.com.myapp.prod",
                "paths": ["/prod/*"]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

- Now i'm able to see the banner on the top of the website `Open with App Dev` as expected

Comment: Can you please share your `apple-app-site-association` file here?

Comment: Great! So now your issue has been resolved, would you please take a moment & mark my answer as accepted & also upvote, so everyone who has the same issue can find it here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify which path is to be opened by which app

For example, your domain is example.com

You have to specify a different path pattern for both dev & prod app in your `apple-app-site-association` file

For example, you can update your `apple-app-site-association` file as shown below

```
{
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [
            {
                "appID": "1234.com.myapp.dev",
                "paths": ["/dev/*"]
            },
            {
                "appID": "1234.com.myapp.prod",
                "paths": ["/prod/*"]
            },
        ]
    }
}
```

Now, let us say you click on the urls below, you'll be directed to mentioned app in the comments

- https://example.com/dev/123?id=3 // Opens dev app
- https://example.com/dev?id=2 // Opens dev app
- https://example.com/prod/123 // Opens prod app
- https://example.com/prod // Opens prod app
- https://example.com/prod/123?name=john // Opens prod app